# При обращении к методу из другого класса происходит сбой приложения

Tags: java, android

У меня есть два класса:
MainActivity и nightMain
Так же в методе nightMain объявил MainActivity:

```
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity ();
```

В MainActivity присутствует метод startM:

```
public void startM() {
button.setText("hello");
}
```

При обращении к этому методу в классе nightMain приложение даёт сбой. Подскажите, что делать?
P.s я новичок в java

Comment: Что за сбой? Исключение? Если да, то приложите стек-трейс, если нет, то попытайтесь объяснить, какой-именно сбой.

Comment: Одна активность не имеет права обращаться к полям и методам другой - не то чтобы это в принципе невозможно, но кроме проблем и недоразумений, ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет. В вашем случае, видимо, надо использовать наследование, но для конкретики недостаточно информации. Поясните подробнее для чего вам вызывать метод другой активности, что вы вообще хотите сделать.

Comment: Вот так `MainActivity ma = new MainActivity ();` делать никогда нельзя. Активити должна создаваться системой, не вами. Вы не присоединяете её к контексту и она просто не будет работать. Получайте ссылку на активити как-то иначе. Хотя бы и кастованием контекста. Или раскрывайте детали задачи - может быть надо иначе делать.

Comment: Я хотел объявить метод из стороннего класса для того, чтобы сменить картинку в imageView Main класса из nightMain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Детали мне неизвестны - ответ на догадках.
Допустим в классе `MainActivity` создаётся и используется объект класса `NightMain` (классы принято именовать с большой буквы) и вы хотите что-то вызывать, возвращать обратно в `MainActivity`.
Тогда нужно классу `NightMain` передать ссылку на `MainActivity` и обращаться через эту ссылку.

Пример одного из вариантов вышеописанного.
Где-то в `MainActivity`:

```
// передаём ссылку через конструктор при создании экземпляра
// this - специальная ссылка, указывающая на текущий объект
NightMain nMain = new NightMain(MainActivity.this);
// дальше делаем что хотим с этим объектом
```

В классе `NightMain`:

```
// объявляем поле для сохранения ссылки на активность
private final MainActivity mainActivity;

// объявляем конструктор с параметром нашей активности
public NightMain(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    // сохраняем ссылку в поле класса
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

// дальше где-то в коде этого класса мы можем вызывать нужный нам метод
    mainActivity.startM();
```

Answer (score 0):

как сказали в комментах - нельзя так делать.
если ты хочешь, в nightMain активити вызвать метод из MainActivity , то тебе надо:

в MainActivity добавить

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static MainActivity instance; // это 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        instance = this; // это 
    }

    // вот это 
    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

   // тут, сообственно, твой метод
    public void myMethod() {
       // do something...
    }
    }
```

А чтобы вызвать в любой другом активити, достаточно

```
MainActivity.getInstance().myMethod();
```

Comment: А вот так лучше не делать - почитайте предупреждение, которым студия ругает поле  `instance`, потом почитайте что это за утечка памяти такая и чем это грозит.